# Cordova Facebook plugin : login error after logout

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using **Cordova 3.0** and the latest [Facebook ConnectPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin), after a `FB.logout(...)` when I do a `FB.login(...)` it switches to the facebook app and i got a

> **No internet connection**
>   
> You have to connect at least once to play

and in the Android console :

> ConnectPlugin : facebook error

even with my device on wifi.

The same error seams to appear on iOS too.

If I go to my facebook account and delete App permission I can log me in again.

Does somebody know how can i fix that ?

**EDIT :** i have this problem on my Nexus 7 with an account but not on my Nexus S in an other account...

**EDIT 2 :** It's the method `permissions.oauth` which throw this error when it calls `FB._nativeInterface`, it throws the error

> Facebook error: Failed to receive access token